# How to scan an entire network using Nmap?

Tags: networking, connection, nmap

Is there a way to scan an entire network using [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/)?

What I want to do is scan my network for all the devices that are currently connected to it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Scan a network and find out which servers and devices are up and running:

```bash
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

Scan a single host:

```bash
nmap 192.168.1.2
```

Scan multiple IP addresses or subnets:

```bash
nmap 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.3
```

Scan by excluding a host:

```bash
nmap 192.168.1.0/24 --exclude 192.168.1.10
```

That will exclude the host while scanning.

Fast nmap scanning for a network range:

```bash
nmap -F 192.168.1.10/24
```

To see packets sent and received received using nmap:

```bash
nmap --packet-trace 192.168.1.10
```

Scan for a port:

```bash
nmap -p 22 192.168.1.10
```

Scan for multiple ports:

```bash
nmap -p 80,22,21,111
```

Scan all ports using nmap:

```bash
nmap -p "*" 192.168.1.10
```

I hope that will help you. If you need to know more just run the command:

```bash
man nmap
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend this has helped me tremendously.  Just to be clear is that IP address 192.168.1.0 a universal network IP or what?  Just curious lol.

Comment: No its your local Network , Network Address

Comment: Option `-sP` is deprecated. The new equivalent is `-sn`.

Comment: `sudo arpscan list` is probably worth looking at to if you're just wanting a list of hosts/clients in the network you're connected to.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve something similar using the IP command?

Answer (score 0):

for entire scan you should be use -p- it means all port scannig .You need to scan entire server with subnet you should use command 192.168.1.1-255.1.255 first you add   hope you got it if i had any mistake please comment.