# How to find some PC in the network

Tags: networking

I have a PC connected to a network where many other devices are. For some unknown reason today the PC is not responding me (I cannot ssh into it), I don't know if the IP changed or what. So from another PC in that network I am trying to list all devices connected to the network and filter by PC maker, operating system, system name, etc. to locate this missing PC. How can this be done? I have been looking at many different options using `apr-scan` and some other apps, but cannot find one in which I see all the information I want.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1451527) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1450494) are related and might help.

Answer (score 1):

Have no idea what `apr-scan` is, but I know that you can use `nmap` to locate your PC. Just install it `sudo apt install nmap`, and then go through this article --> [How to scan an entire network using Nmap?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377787/how-to-scan-an-entire-network-using-nmap)

Comment: The OP probably means [`arp-scan`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/arp-scan.1.html)

Comment: Yeah, I guess so